# How can I set a text template on edit for Rails-Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

It's just a question.

Is it possible to set a text template on edit for Rails-Admin?


Whenever inputting some data, it takes a long time.

So, I think if I can call like a mail template, it would takes a short.


I searched that kind of the function for Rails-Admin but I couldn't find it..

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want a fill-in-the-blanks kind of template? So the user only fills up some words that form part of a large body of text?

Comment: yes! that's what I want!

Comment: How dynamic is this template? does it change often? is it defined in another place? or is it a once of a kind thing?

Comment: It's not change often. I hope we can choose few templates from editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails admin does not have anything special that can help you with this. The edit view, the closest thing that could help you, is auto-generated from the model fields and associations. And unless you want to add a model for each template you probably should steer clear of this approach.

What you need is to build a custom action. You'd have to practically build everything like a regular controller.
Check out the [actions page of the rails admin wiki](https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/wiki/Actions) for instructions on how to do this.

Good luck

Comment: ohh, that's helpful! Thank you!